# URL.createObjectURL() GET net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, typescript, blob

## I will try to load video with URL.createObjectURL()

It's working fine, but when I try to call `URL.revokeObjectURL()`,
video play for seconds and then pause, and in the console tab I get `net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` error:

[image]

```js
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
  const video = document.getElementById('video');
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);

  video.src = url;


  setTimeout(() => {
      URL.revokeObjectURL(video.src);
  }, 0)
})
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file" />
<video id="video" controls muted></video>
```

Comment: Your code is working fine for me.

Comment: Hello, i think work same as my , play video for seconds and then stop. Please try with google chrome